# Table created using PHP has attribute display:none

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm struggling with a strange error. 
I create an HTML table from a mysql query using PHP like so:

```
echo "<div id=\"table_div\">";
echo "<table id=\"ad_table\">"; 
echo "<tr id=\"table_header\"><td>Media Id</td><td> Company</td><td>Title/Claim</td><td>Start - End</td><td>Website/Email</td><td></td></\td></tr>";  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr id= " . $row['Id']. "><td><b>" .$row['Titel'] . "</b> <br>"  . $row['Offer'] . "</td><td><button class=\"del_btn\" rel=" . $id . ">Delete</button> </td></\td></tr>";  
 }
 echo "</table>"; 
 echo "</div>";
```

But the table is not visible. I can inspect the HTML and table and all expected rows are present but the table class has the attribute display: none. The style is not coming from my stylesheet (I tried it without providing any). I don't know why the table is hidden. Happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an adblocker installed? Stuff like `id="ad_table"` can trigger it.

Comment: Its either what Wesley said in above comment, or you have some javascript in page thats actively hiding #ad_table

Comment: are you sure that $row has records?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices.

Comment: Try loading the page with JS disabled, if it shows up then there is some Javascript at work that is hiding the table. That should be a fun hunt :)

Comment: Why `\t` in `</\td>` that makes it `</     d>`. Your attribute values should also be quoted.

Comment: @WesleyMurch that was it. I didn't think of that. Thanks so much.

Comment: @tadman thanks, I will look into PDO.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by AdBlock browser plugin

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, due to the presence of `ad_table` triggering the AdBlocker as explained by @Wesley Murch in the OP comments